# Use the ascii code of a character as an input to sort

Tags: linux, shell, freebsd, sorting, ascii

I'd like to sort a file with a specific delimiter (ascii 0xff) and the records are zero-terminated. I cannot use the following command though:

```
$ sort -z -t \xff -o data data
```

The error message is:

On FreeBSD:

```
sort: xff: Invalid argument
```

and on Linux:

```
sort: multi-character tab ‘xff’
```

Is there a way to do so in a portable fashion? (across gnu coreutils sort and bsd sort and across different shells).

Comment: Not sure about FreeBSD (depends on the shell, also), but in bash in Linux, you can use `$'\xff'`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. It works on Linux but not on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, that `$'\xff'` is actually a [Bash feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) and should be OS agnostic. This works here on FreeBSD 9.1 (tried bash, ksh, zsh):

```
$ head -3 foo
26436�22977
4478�3214
28822�4147

$ head -3 foo | sort -n -t $'\xff' -k2
4478�3214
28822�4147
26436�22977
```

OK, if this doesn't work, maybe it will work with (BSD-)awk:

```
$ head -3 a | awk -F $'\xff' '{print $1" "$2}' | sort -nk2 | awk '{print $1"\xff"$2}'
4478�3214
28822�4147
26436�22977
```

Yes, it's ugly :-\

Comment: I tried this on FreeBSD 10.0 on tcsh, zsh and bash and it did not work on any of them.